# Change the text of the option with empty value of a specific select with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Suppose a page with two hierarchical select boxes. One holds the regions, and according to the selected region, a second select appears with the areas of that region.

Unfortunately the system that generates them, sets the same placeholder for both, so both selects' default value (value="") is "Select Region".

So, I want to change on-the-fly the default value of the second one to "Select Area".

You can distinguish the second selects by their data-level attribute.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //alert($('select.listdom-location[data-level="2"]').find('option:empty').text());
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lsd-search-filter lsd-col-10">
  <label for="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location">Regions</label>
  <div class="lsd-hierarchical-dropdowns" id="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location_wrapper" data-for="listdom-location" data-id="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location" data-max-levels="2" data-name="sf-listdom-location" data-hide-empty="0">
    <select class="listdom-location" name="sf-listdom-location" id="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location_1" placeholder="Select Region" data-level="1">
      <option value="">Select Region</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-0" value="289">Region 1</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-0" value="391">Region 2</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-0" value="290">Region 3</option>
    </select>
    <select class="listdom-location" name="" id="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location_2" placeholder="Select Region" data-level="2">
      <option value="">Select Region</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-289" value="291">Area 1</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-289" value="292">Area 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me change with jQuery on page load the default option to "Select Area" please?

Comment: Where is the "Select Area"?

Comment: It's the second select (with data-level="2")

Comment: Update it in what way? There is no Select Area at first. There are two Select Region and want to change the second one to Select Area on the fly. Maybe you didn't get my post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based @Geshode's answer above, I was able to figure out the correct code to use!

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select.listdom-location[data-level="2"] option[value=""]').text("Select Area")
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lsd-search-filter lsd-col-10">
  <label for="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location">Regions</label>
  <div class="lsd-hierarchical-dropdowns" id="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location_wrapper" data-for="listdom-location" data-id="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location" data-max-levels="2" data-name="sf-listdom-location" data-hide-empty="0">
    <select class="listdom-location" name="sf-listdom-location" id="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location_1" placeholder="Select Region" data-level="1">
      <option value="">Select Region</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-0" value="289">Region 1</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-0" value="391">Region 2</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-0" value="290">Region 3</option>
    </select>
    <select class="listdom-location" name="" id="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location_2" placeholder="Select Region" data-level="2">
      <option value="">Select Region</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-289" value="291">Area 1</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-289" value="292">Area 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible ways to do that.

One possibility:

```js
$('#lsd_search_10574_listdom-location_2 option[value=""]').text("Select Area")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lsd-search-filter lsd-col-10">
  <label for="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location">Regions</label>
  <div class="lsd-hierarchical-dropdowns" id="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location_wrapper" data-for="listdom-location" data-id="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location" data-max-levels="2" data-name="sf-listdom-location" data-hide-empty="0">
    <select class="listdom-location" name="sf-listdom-location" id="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location_1" placeholder="Select Region" data-level="1">
      <option value="">Select Region</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-0" value="289">Region 1</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-0" value="391">Region 2</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-0" value="290">Region 3</option>
    </select>
    <select class="listdom-location" name="" id="lsd_search_10574_listdom-location_2" placeholder="Select Region" data-level="2">
      <option value="">Select Region</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-289" value="291">Area 1</option>
      <option class="lsd-option lsd-parent-289" value="292">Area 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

You select the default option, which has an empty string as its value, of the second select, which has the id `lsd_search_10574_listdom-location_2` and then you change its text to `Select Area`.

Comment: It won't always be that id though... That's why I mentioned that I have to use the class of the select (that is listdom-location), and then, use the data attribute data-level to further filter the one with data-level="2"